# NodeJS и MySQL, pool connetctions

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Есть express, установлен модуль mysql, цель: соединиться с базой где-то в каком-то месте один раз, и не делать в разных скриптах, в т.ч. и скриптах других моих модулей подобное:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'user',
  password : '1111',
  database : 'test'
});

connection.connect(function(err){
  if(!err) {
    console.log("Database is connected ");
  } else {
    console.log("Error connecting database ");
  }
});
```

При этом, нужно ли мне использовать pool запросов? Если да, то как правильно к этому подойти? Весь смысл в том, чтобы понять как данное соединение сделать глобальным чтобы его повсеместно использовать, и так чтобы это не вызвало нагрузки на систему и со временем не повесило мускул.
p.s. мои знания того как это работает в  node.js - сыры пока что, очень надеюсь на детальное изъяснение решения по данной задаче.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте по порядку.

Для начала, о необходимости использования пула. [Драйвер mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/) обрабатывает запросы в каждом подключении последовательно (хотя и асинхронно). Поэтому если у вашего приложения больше одного клиента, то для каждого из них необходимо создавать свое собственное подключение к БД. Или же использовать пул соединений, значительно облегчающий жизнь во многих аспектах (контроль максимального количества подключений, переоткрытие подключений, ...).

А теперь несколько слов о глобальных переменных в node.js.

Node.js кэширует вызовы `require`, поэтому логику подключения к БД (и хранения внутреннего состояния) можно реализовать в одном из модулей. Предположим, есть модуль `lib/mysql_pool.js` с таким вот кодом:

```
var mysql = require('mysql'),
    pool = null;

exports.connect = function(options) {
    pool = mysql.createPool(options);
};

exports.getInstance = function() {
    if (!pool) {
        throw new Error('Connect the pool first');
    }

    return pool;
};
```

Далее, в процессе инициализации приложения вы инициализируете и пул соединений:

```
var pool = require('./lib/mysql_pool');

pool.connect({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'user',
    password: '1111',
    database: 'test'
});
```

И там, где собственно необходимо соединение с базой можно выполнить:

```
var pool = require('./lib/mysql_pool');

pool.getInstance().getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    // ... do something cool
    connection.release();
});
```

P.S.: На мой взгляд, правильнее было бы создавать пул соединений на этапе инициализации приложения и прередавать его в явном виде между модулями. Это несколько увеличит объем необходимого кода, зато позволит полностью отказаться от магии `require` (и глобального состояния) и упростит модульное тесторование.